# Raw Sql vs SqlAlchemy when Django ORM is not enough

Tags: sql, orm, django

In a django project, if a situation comes that Django ORM is not able to execute some complex queries then there are 2 options:

1. Use Raw Sql queries
2. Use SqlAlchemy

I want to know if there are some rules like some pros and cons of both which can guide me to choose one of the above 2 options. 
Or is it entirely depends on what we like?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**ORM**

- *Pro* Usable on different DBMS without code customization.
- *Pro* Makes code/DB integration easier.
- *Pro* Additional type checking from ORM/table definitions.
- *Pro* Facilitate db migrations.
- *Pro* Essentially a DSL for DB integration.
- *Con* Additional component to understand *(you should understand how the ORM will create the SQL)*
- *Con* Any SQL customizations eliminate the usability on different DBMS.

**Raw SQL**

- *Pro* You know the SQL being used because it's there in the code.
- *Pro* More control over the SQL and integration.
- *Pro* Less complexity (no ORM).
- *Con* Tied to one DBMS flavor of SQL.
- *Con* Manual code/DB integration.

**The issue of complexity**

I'm sure I'll get dinged for this, BUT.

Unlike many of the its proponents I do NOT think ORMs free the developers from understanding SQL.  You still have to understand SQL because you will end up dealing with the SQL your ORM creates.  And here is why:

- SQL statements are typically one of the first things that needs performance tuning in a given project.
- ORMs are still young.  None that I know of implement an actual SQL parser which means, outside of trivial statements, the SQL constructed is often inefficient, and in some cases just wrong.

This doesn't mean you shouldn't use an ORM.  They can still reduce the amount of code you have to write.  But you should understand you may not get all the benefits you think you will.

Comment: I agree with you on understanding sql first. I am actually first trying out my sql queries on the database to get better understanding of it and for future tuning needs. I will use django orm and wherever I see that django generated queries are not good and can be improved I will use raw sql or sqlalchemy. I am not afraid to code more if it gives me better performance.